# Unchecked state of radio button shows nothing

Tags: android, radio-button

So, below is an image of my RadioGroup.
[image]

and this is my code:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_flowers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_amaryllis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amaryllis"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_rose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rose"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

As shown above, `Rose` which is in `unchecked` state, shows nothing. But if I tapped it, it would becomes green, and `Amaryllis` would show nothing.

I suspected this is related to android theme, but I can't seem to find how to change RadioButton theme... I've tried change the style with `selector`, where, following some tutorial, put the `drawable` as `android:button`, but instead, the button lost and only the label left, shifting to left because it seems that there isn't buttons.

So, where's the circle when it's in `unchecked` state? What should I do fix it? I just want it to show grey circle when it's in unchecked state.

Btw I didn't try something like setTint because minimum requirement is below API 21.

Comment: could you please add your code

Comment: Thanks for telling me, code added. That's all the code to show it.

Comment: using support lib v7? or not?

Comment: have you set any theme for your activity? What is the theme set for your application

Comment: hmm where to see that? in `manifest`, the activity only has this for theme-related thingy: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`